# Groovy Map/Reduce for Jenkins DSL

Tags: functional-programming, groovy, mapreduce

Jenkins DSL doesn't support `collect` and `inject` from what I can tell (I get missing method exceptions when I try), so I implemented my own map & reduce functions to use. I'm not sure if there's much to say about this small snippet of code, but I'd love to hear from some groovy or FP folks.

```
def map = { collection, f ->
  def result = []
  collection.each { element ->
    result.add(f(element))
  }
  result
}

def reduce = { collection, accumulator, f ->
  def result = accumulator
  collection.each { element ->
    result = f(result, element)
  }
  result
}
```